# download prompt instead of default index because of a site dir name change

Tags: lamp

cakephp v1.3.2 unchanged at /var/www/cakephp displays the cakephp default index page
cakephp v1.3.2 unchanged at /var/www/iloved prompts me to download a phtml file

a2enmod php5 says php5 is installed
apache2 was restarted

Why? How to solve?

phpmyadmin is installed, but not loading too (localhost/phpmyadmin says Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The troubleshoot for "apache2: Could not determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName" works for download prompt instead of site too.

It's like this:

use a text editor such as "sudo nano" at the command line or "gksudo gedit" on the desktop to create a new file,

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn`

or

`gksu "gedit /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn"`

then add

ServerName localhost

to the file and save. This can all be done in a single command with the following:

echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn"