# while trying to view phpinfo.php, I get a prompt for download

Tags: apache-2.2, kubuntu

I tried:

sudo apt-get --purge remove php5-common
sudo apt-get install php5 phpmyadmin
sudo a2enmod php5
adding Servername localhost to /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn

Apache isn't recognizing php (instead prompting for download). How to make it correctly execute php?

Comment: How do you know it is not recognizing PHP? What is the error message?

Comment: The php info is intended to print / echo things, not prompt for download.

Comment: You need to isolate the problem further. What's in /etc/apache2/mods-available? The `sudo a2enmod` command requires as argument. Can you run PHP from the command line? `php -r 'echo "hello";'`.

Comment: There are lots of things in mod-available. I had run sudo a2enmod php5, but wrote it wrong in the question. I can run php from command-line.

Comment: In mods-available, there are php5.conf, php5.load, php5filter.conf, php5filter.load. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: This and your [previous question](http://serverfault.com/questions/170375/download-prompt-instead-of-default-index-because-of-a-site-dir-name-change) on the same issue don't have enough detail. Look at your apache configuration, it probably enforces a separation of data and programs, with the latter in cgi-bin.

Answer (score 1):

Missing AddHandler for .php?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following in your configuration somewhere (it can be in the vhost definition or prior to it):
`AddHandler php5-script .php`

Comment: Either in the main configuration file or an include. Given that you're using Ubuntu, it's likely to be either /etc/apache2/apache2.conf or /etc/apache2/sites-available/somefile.conf

Comment: I added AddHandler php5-script .php to httpd.conf, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I don't think httpd.conf is used by Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried the bottom of apache2.conf too, but it didn't work.

Comment: The bottom of apache2.conf is unlikely to help you. Basically you need to put it *before* the vhost definition, bearing in mind that the file is read from top to bottom and, as far as I know, Include files are entirely read *before* the next line. Paste your apache2.conf somewhere (eg. pastie.org) and we can take a look for you.

Comment: I accidentally deleted vhost_alias.load.

Comment: I reinstalled apache2, but vhost_alias.load is still missing.

Comment: I reinstalled Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

install LAMP in Kubuntu with:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

restart Apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

create phpinfo.php with:

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

place phpinfo.php in /var/www

clear browser cache

visit http://localhost/phpinfo.php

that should show the phpinfo